# How to fix NoSuchFieldError 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-plugin, lombok

How can i fix 'java: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid'' error?

When I research the problem, I encountered Java version and lombok version incompatibility problem.
I use java 19 and lombok 1.18.20 version in my spring boot project. How can I fix this problem without using jdk21?

Comment: Lombok 1.18.20 is a very old version. Upgrade to 1.18.30.

Comment: @rzwitserloot is correct, I was using lombok artifact earlier version `1.18.24` and got this above OP question, simply followed his comment and replaced with `1.18.30` and that worked fine.

Comment: I have this same error, but it happens when I try to run JUnit tests in maven with jdk 21. The issue has to do with incompatible versions somwhere in the dependencies. Dropping the project's jdk back to jdk17 solves the issue for me.

Comment: Still facing the error although I've already updated lombok to 1.18.30

Comment: make sure your project setting use java 19.